# Accuracy of Google Maps latitude and longitude?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, accuracy

I am making a program that uses GPS location preferably from smart phone, laptop works too and compares it to a building, the points you in its general direction. I am making this web application specifically for San Jose State Campus for fun. I have read the other posts about the correlation between decimal places and accuracy and a .11m error will be sufficient. Google maps gives me coordinates to the 6th decimal place, I was wondering if they do indeed follow the standard I have read about here. Here is an example of one of the buildings I will index.

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%2B38%C2%B0+34%27+24.00%22,+-109%C2%B0+32%27+57.00%22&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wl

I will only have an arrow point in the direction of the building and rotate it as the lat/long of the user changes and maybe display the approximate distance from the building. I have yet to learn how to properly use google api to draw the users path and etc and that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 5):

A quick search (using no other than our great search engine god, Google) led me to this [site](http://hobiger.org/blog/2013/04/20/horizontal-positional-accuracy-of-google-maps/), which further linked me to two articles.

The author summarizes:

D. Potere, [Horizontal Positional Accuracy of Google Earth’s High-Resolution Imagery Archive](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/8/12/7973/pdf), Sensors 2008, 8, 7973-7981.

> This paper is more than five years old and the author used control points derived from
>   satellite imagery. He ended up with a root-mean square error (RMSE) accuracy of 22.8 meters.

S.C. Benker et al., [Positional accuracy of the Google Earth terrain model derived from stratigraphic unconformities in the Big Bend region](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10106049.2011.568125), Texas, USA. Geocarto International 2011, 26, 1–13.

> Here the authors find a horizontal position accuracy of 2.64 m RMSE with a mean offset distance being of about 7m w.r.t. a high accurate terrain model.

Comment: Great resources, Paul.  I often find it interesting how different the positional accuracy can be looking at the historical imagery in Google Earth of the same location!